# Combining flat_map and zip when reading TensorFlow Dataset from multiple files: Are files being read from disk a second time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Following up on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037100/tensorflow-example-implementation-of-a-simple-custom-transformation-func-for-da), I am using `tf.data.Dataset.zip(dataset, dataset.skip(1))` to generate a dataset of successive items. I am doing this since I want my model_fn to be fed two successive frames at a time from which it calculates the difference.

When reading from multiple `tfrecords` files on disk, I have run into the problem that the correct order of records in my dataset is sometimes not maintained in my current implementation. The simplified problem can be reproduced as:

*file1.txt* (file2.txt looks the same with `f2_i01,1` etc.)

```
f1_i01,1
f1_i02,2
f1_i03,3
f1_i04,4
f1_i05,5
```

My code

```py
import tensorflow as tf

COLUMNS = ['image', 'label']
FIELD_DEFAULTS = [['empty'], [0]]

def _line_parser(line):
    fields = tf.decode_csv(line, FIELD_DEFAULTS)
    data = dict(zip(COLUMNS, fields))
    label = data.pop('label')
    return data, label

filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filenames)
dataset = files.flat_map(
    lambda filename:
        tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename)
        .map(_line_parser))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, dataset.skip(1)))

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.initializer

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(5):
        print(sess.run(next_element))
```

If I execute this code, I get *one of* the following results, seemingly at random:

Option 1.1: Order maintained (file1.txt read first)

```
(({'image': b'f1_i01'}, 1), ({'image': b'f1_i02'}, 2))
(({'image': b'f1_i02'}, 2), ({'image': b'f1_i03'}, 3))
(({'image': b'f1_i03'}, 3), ({'image': b'f1_i04'}, 4))
(({'image': b'f1_i04'}, 4), ({'image': b'f1_i05'}, 5))
(({'image': b'f1_i05'}, 5), ({'image': b'f2_i01'}, 1))
```

Option 1.2: Order maintained (file2.txt read first)

```
(({'image': b'f2_i01'}, 1), ({'image': b'f2_i02'}, 2))
(({'image': b'f2_i02'}, 2), ({'image': b'f2_i03'}, 3))
(({'image': b'f2_i03'}, 3), ({'image': b'f2_i04'}, 4))
(({'image': b'f2_i04'}, 4), ({'image': b'f2_i05'}, 5))
(({'image': b'f2_i05'}, 5), ({'image': b'f1_i01'}, 1))
```

Option 2.1: Order not maintained (file1.txt read first)

```
(({'image': b'f1_i01'}, 1), ({'image': b'f2_i02'}, 2))
(({'image': b'f1_i02'}, 2), ({'image': b'f2_i03'}, 3))
(({'image': b'f1_i03'}, 3), ({'image': b'f2_i04'}, 4))
(({'image': b'f1_i04'}, 4), ({'image': b'f2_i05'}, 5))
(({'image': b'f1_i05'}, 5), ({'image': b'f1_i01'}, 1))
```

Option 2.2: Order not maintained (file2.txt read first)

```
(({'image': b'f2_i01'}, 1), ({'image': b'f1_i02'}, 2))
(({'image': b'f2_i02'}, 2), ({'image': b'f1_i03'}, 3))
(({'image': b'f2_i03'}, 3), ({'image': b'f1_i04'}, 4))
(({'image': b'f2_i04'}, 4), ({'image': b'f1_i05'}, 5))
(({'image': b'f2_i05'}, 5), ({'image': b'f2_i01'}, 1))
```

It seems to me like the zip function causes the dataset to be read from disk a second time independently. Is there any way that I can consistently achieve Option 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think that this is confusing because I wouldn't expect zip to cause files to be read a second time.

However, in my case, it turns out all I needed to do was adding `shuffle=False` argument to `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to achieve Option 1 consistently.